# Unable to serialize value

Tags: magento2

I've changed cache management to disable and i have worked for a while after that I've changed to cache enable by the time im getting above error, guys can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: please provide stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

**To Solve The issue Please Check This Link**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921801/9956270